# VirtualBox installation: part of screen missing

Tags: virtualbox

In VirtualBox during installation there is the right part of the screen missing, I guess there should be a next button.
anyway, somehow I managed to get through the wizard with lots of returns and cursor downs.

Is there a way to make the experience better?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not a fantastic solution, but you can actually drag the window left and right.

Answer (score 0):

That's a common problem with VirtualBox since the automatic resize function only works if you have the guest additions installed.
If you use the "Try Ubuntu" or in this case "Try Kubuntu" option you can change the resolutionfrom the settings manager to something bigger. After that, when you start the installation the installer window can fit without being outside the visual area.